# X Logical Font Description and HiDPI

Tags: x11, fonts, x-resources, dpi, high-dpi

**The problem**: X-server serves fonts at a fixed resolution of **100dpi**, rather than the current window system resolution (`xdpyinfo | grep -F resolution`).

**A bit of theory**. There are legacy server-side fonts which are sent to X clients over the network (via TCP or UNIX socket) either by the X server itself, or by a separate *X Font Server* (single or multiple). Unlike the usual client-side fonts (Xft, GTK 2+, Qt 2+), the "server" backend (also called the *core X font* backend) does not support anti-aliasing, but supports network transparency (that is, bitmaps, without any alpha channel, are sent over the network). At the application level, server-side fonts are specified not as an [`XftFontStruct`](https://keithp.com/%7Ekeithp/talks/xtc2001/paper/) (which most often translates into the familiar `DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12:antialias=true`), but as an [*XLFD*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_Logical_Font_Description). If we are talking about a local machine, then the same font file can be registered in both font backends at once and be available to both modern GTK and Qt-based applications, and legacy ones (Xt, Athena, Motif, GTK 1.2, Qt 1.x).

Historically, there were raster server-side fonts (`*.pcf`), and a raster has a resolution of its own (not necessarily the same as the window system resolution). Therefore, XLFD has fields such as `RESOLUTION_X` and `RESOLUTION_Y`. For a raster font not to look ugly when rendered onto the screen and still have the requested rasterized glyph size (`PIXEL_SIZE`), the raster resolution must be close to the screen resolution, therefore raster fonts were usually shipped with native resolutions of **75dpi** and **100dpi** (that's why we still have directories such as `/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi` and `/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi`). So, the below lines represent the same 12 pt font

```
-bitstream-charter-bold-r-normal--12-120-75-75-p-75-iso8859-1
-bitstream-charter-bold-r-normal--17-120-100-100-p-107-iso8859-1
```

with a rasterized glyph size of

- **12px** at **75dpi**, and
- **17px** at **100dpi**, respectively.

But, in addition to raster fonts, there are vector, or outline fonts (*TrueType*, *OpenType*, *Adobe Type 1*), which can be scaled by any factor and still look good when rendered onto the screen. Some X-server implementations (notably, *XSun*) also supported the *Adobe Type 3* format, where glyphs were described using the Turing-complete *PostScript* language.

Of course, the concept of raster resolution does not apply to vector fonts, so I can request zeroes (`0`) or even asterisks (`*`) in the `RESOLUTION_X` and `RESOLUTION_Y` fields, and, in theory, my X server should give me exactly the font requested. This is directly stated in the *Arch Linux Wiki* article at the link above:

> Scalable fonts were designed to be resized. A scalable font name, as shown in the example below, has zeroes in the pixel and point size fields, the two resolution fields, and the average width field.
>
> ...
>
> To specify a scalable font at a particular size you only need to provide a value for the `POINT_SIZE` field, the other size related values ​​can remain at zero. The `POINT_SIZE` value is in tenths of a point, so the entered value must be the desired point size multiplied by ten.

So, either of the following two queries should return a **12pt** `Courier New` font at the window system resolution:

```
-monotype-courier new-medium-r-normal--*-120-*-*-m-*-iso10646-1
-monotype-courier new-medium-r-normal--0-120-0-0-m-0-iso10646-1
```

**Or so I thought**. The thing is, after migration from 96...115dpi monitors to a **162dpi** 4k monitor, I noticed that my carefully selected vector fonts suddenly became too small.

And it turned out that unless you explicitly set `RESOLUTION_X` and `RESOLUTION_Y` fields to **162** (and no one in his right mind would do so -- it would require rewriting dozens of `Xresources` lines every time one changes his monitor), then X server defaults to rendering the font at **100dpi** instead of **162**. The difference between **17** and **27** pixels (the factor of `1.62 = 162 / 100`) is quite noticeable. Here's an example for a modern *Debian 10* box:

[image: Debian 10, Courier New 12pt at 162dpi]

I thought this regression was a consequence of people gradually cutting out obsolete subsystems from X11, but in *Debian Woody*, released in 2002 and having a 2.2 kernel, I saw exactly the same thing:

[image: Debian 3, Courier New 12pt at 162dpi]

The only difference is that *Debian Woody* renders fonts in a "cleaner" manner, apparently, applying hinting on the server side, before sending bitmaps over the network.

So this is not a regression. The problem has always been there and equally affects all vector font types (*TrueType*, *OpenType*, *Type 1*).

**Now, the question**. Is there a way, without hard-coding window system resolution into user settings for each individual resource, to get by with less pain than recommended by the author of the [*Sharing Xresources between systems*](https://jnrowe.github.io/articles/tips/Sharing_Xresources_between_systems.html) article?

Is it possible to solve the problem by changing the global configuration of the X server itself or the libraries it relies on (`libfreetype`, `libxfont`)?

Comment: this is a brilliantly asked question - shame about the lack of an answer : )